# Are there any memory utlization issue with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB for xml parsing, are there any performance or memory utilization issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing to be mindful of is that `JAXBContext.newInstance()` is a very slow operation. This is where a lot of reflection and class generation happens, leading to perm space issues mentioned by duffymo. Thankfully, `JAXBContext` is thread-safe, so it's ok to [cache one away and reuse it](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html). Otherwise, I think it's safe to say that JAXB memory usage will be on-par (or maybe less) than a full DOM, and, of course, greater than SAX.

If you have very large documents, it's possible to [process them in chunks with JAXB](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_large_documents.html#Processing_a_document_by_chunk). The [JAXB RI distribution](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList) includes an example of streaming with JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

JAXB suffers from the same basic issues as DOM-based parsing, which is that generally speaking, the entire data data structure is held in memory at the same time. That said, it's generally less memory-hungry than a DOM API (with the possible exception of XOM).

Having said that, there are ways of using JAXB to read fragments of large documents in a stream-oriented fashion, if needs be. That's fairly exotic usage, though.

Comment: can you explain using JAXB as SAX like parser?

Comment: @Jimmy: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_large_documents.html#Processing%5Fa%5Fdocument%5Fby%5Fchunk

Answer (score 2):

You may indeed run into performance and memory issues with Java XML data binding due to excessive object creation/destruction, [this article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/09/07/schema-less-java-xml-data-binding-with-vtd-xml.html) may help 
explain a new data binding technique that may help avoiding those issues

Answer (score 1):

JAXB has the additional issue of using reflection to create classes that are added to your perm space as it runs.  OutOfMemoryError mayhem can ensue.

Comment: Much [relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33431431/122727) about noOptimize.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that performance can be hit pretty badly with JAXB as opposed to more 'simple' XML handling mechanisms in Java such as the Xerces [`SAXParser`](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/XML/XML-Parsing-With-SAX-and-Xerces-part-1/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding below JVM argument can fix this issue (with slight performance impact)

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2939