# After multiple weblogic deployments "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, weblogic, application-server

```
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace     at

> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at
> weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412)
```

Exception after 5-6 deployments to weblogicServer cluster with the help of Jenkins, build tool used is Ant. Restarting the ManagedServer and Adminconsole temporarily fixes the issue.

Possible duplicate : [java8 "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051813/java8-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-metaspace)

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotcha !

Admin console is currently holding 2 ManagedServers, both ManagedServers having low MaxMetaspaceSize, updated the value from 512 MB to 1024 MB.

```
 XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
```

Issue is fixed !

Reference : [Understand the OutOfMemoryError Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)