# How to prevent a Spring Boot / Tomcat (Java8) process be OOM-killed?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Since moving to Tomcat8/Java8, now and then the Tomcat server is OOM-killed. OOM = Out-of-memory kill by the Linux kernel.

**How can I prevent the Tomcat server be OOM-killed?**

Can this be the result of a memory leak? I guess I would get a normal Out-of-memory message, but no OOM-kill. Correct?

Should I change settings in the HEAP size? 
Should I change settings for the MetaSpace size?

Knowing which Tomcat process is killed, how to retrieve info so that I can reconfigure the Tomcat server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another very good solution is transforming your application to a Spring Boot JAR (Docker) application. Normally this application has a lot less memory consumption.

So steps the get huge improvements (if you can move to Spring Boot application):

- Migrate to Spring Boot application. In my case, this took 3 simple actions.
- Use a light-weight base image. See below.
- **VERY IMPORTANT** - use the Java memory balancing options. See the last line of the Dockerfile below. This reduced my running container RAM usage from over 650MB to **ONLY** 240MB. Running smoothly. So, **SAVING** over 400MB on 650MB!!

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR your.jar
ENV AB_OFF true
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/$JAVA_APP_JAR /deployments/
CMD ["java","-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-jar","/deployments/your.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check that the oomkill isn't being triggered by another process in the system, or that the server isn't overloaded with other processes. It could be that Tomcat is being unfairly targeted by oomkill when some other greedy process is the culprit.

Heap should be set as a maximum size (-Xmx) to be smaller than the physical RAM on the server. If it is more than this, then paging will cause desperately poor performance when garbage collecting.

If it's caused by the metaspace growing in an unbounded fashion, then you need to find out why that is happening. Simply setting the maximum size of metaspace will cause an outofmemory error once you reach the limit you've set. And raising the limit will be pointless, because eventually you'll hit any higher limit you set.

Run your application and **before** it crashes (not easy of course but you'll need to judge it), kill -3 the tomcat process. Then analyse the heap and try to find out why metaspace is growing big. It's usually caused by dynamically loading classes. Is this something your application is doing? More likely, it's some framework doing this. (Nb oom killer will kill -9 the tomcat process, and you won't be able to diagnostics after that, so you need to let the app run and intervene before this happens).

Check out also this question - there's an intriguing answer which claims an obscure fix to an XML binding setting cleared the problem (highly questionable but may be worth a try) [java8 "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051813/java8-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-metaspace)