# After upgrading to Gradle 5 and Android Plugin 3.3, my build fails with "Metaspace"

Tags: android, gradle, metaspace

This happened when I upgraded to Gradle 5.0 from 4.10.3, and also the Android Gradle Plugin from 3.2.1 to 3.3.0-rc03 (the latter because it's the first version of AGP to officially support Gradle 5).

When I attempt to sync my project after this, I get an error. The error only says:

```
* What went wrong:
Metaspace
```

Subsequent builds either also emitted this error, or something even more obscure, like:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class com.gradle.scan.a.e.c
```

There's no obvious solution to this problem. A search for "gradle metaspace" turns up [release notes for Gradle 5](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html), which themselves only refer to it here:

> [#7385](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7385) - Limit Metaspace used by Gradle

And the issue itself isn't the most helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[As we know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131165/what-is-the-difference-between-permgen-and-metaspace), Java 8 removed PermGen and replaced it with Metaspace. Pre-Gradle 5, no max was set for Metaspace, meaning it could grow without bound (which it would only do in the presence of a memory leak, either from a plugin or Gradle itself). With Gradle 5, a maximum limit of 256 MB is now set by default. Once the Gradle process hits this limit, the build will fail with `Metaspace` as the error. This limit is set because it is seen as both "large enough" and sane, and also with the explicit idea to discover memory leaks more quickly. (Source: I work for Gradle.)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051813/java8-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-metaspace) gives a clue, but doesn't directly answer the question.

It turns out that increasing the metaspace limit is simple. Add this to your `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

Or some other value that makes sense to you. 512 is simply twice the default. Obviously this doesn't "fix" the problem, since the problem is a memory leak somewhere. But it will help.

Comment: hello to all the upvoters here that just shove that line into their properties and ignore the leak :)

For me it went away when I ran another build, first build was on a new machine, downloading dependencies must have consumed too much.

Comment: hey don't mess with my source of internet points :)

Comment: Hopefully that fixed the problem.