# Java Non Heap increasing indefinitely

Tags: tomcat, garbage-collection, heap-memory, metaspace

We are working on a new application which is still in non-prod. We are using java 8. The issue we are facing is the non-heap increases gradually, with in few days to a point that it crashes the linux system.

Our application is running on tomcat and we use a automated deployment method. As part of troubleshooting we did the below test.

XMX = 4gb

1. Restarted the Tomcat to give it a fresh start. application started with below stats

   - Heap usage = 1.5gb
   - non-heap = 200mb
2. Without any user testing after tomcat restart, we did a automated deployment, same code just deployed again and noticed the non-heap doubled.

   - Heap usage = 1.5gb
   - non-heap = 400mb

we repeated the deployments multiple times and each time, the non heap increases. Non just the deploy, but just starting/stopping the application(not the tomcat) also increases the non-heap by 200mb.

Basically we narrowed our issue to, when ever we do a deployment the non heap increases. Important thing to note is we don't restart tomcat during the auto deployment. **I'm looking for suggestions on should I include the tomcat restart step after each deployment ? or should I include the XX:MaxMetaspaceSize parameter to put a threshold to non heap ?**

we have been monitoring our regular heap usage and there are no issues. Garbage collection happens in regular intervals and reclaims the space. But this is not the case with NON-HEAP, even when the GC happens no space is reclaimed from the NON-heap.

Answer (score 0):

You should check a potential issue with class loaders, which are loading too many classes and most probably causing this issue.

For example, you can use a tool such as Java Mission Control, just an example, to focus on the highlighted metric below.

[image]

If you see the previous number is increasing over the time, you can use this flag:

```
-verbose:class
```

With previous flag you will get information about class loading that could be used to identify the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> should I include the XX:MaxMetaspaceSize parameter to put a threshold to non heap ?

If Metaspace is growing, sooner or later it will hit that max size threshold and your JVM will eventually crash with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` error.

> I'm looking for suggestions on should I include the tomcat restart step after each deployment ?

If you can afford it, then I will suggest you to include it for now until you resolve the issue.

Also please follow [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36294692/5334745) to collect and diagnose the actual problem in your app. Thanks!