# Out of Memory : Metaspace with java 8

Tags: java-8, jetty-8, metaspace, java-memory-leaks

My product has 256 MB of RAM. I have upgrade java 6 to java 8.
Then I started facing memory related issue with java 8.
memory consumption is incresing by the time with Java 8 
With same code, memory consumption is stable with java 6
I have explored so much regarding metaspace,java8 and found below metaspace parameters.

I have tried below combinations and got out of memory error

**1.MaxMetaspaceSize 50M
  MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio 60M
  MinMetaspaceFreeRatio 50M**

**2.MaxMetaspaceSize 30M**

**3.MaxMetaspaceSize 40M**

**4.MaxMetaspaceSize 50M**

**5.MaxMetaspaceSize 80M**

But after 2 to 3 hours ,outofmemory metaspace error raised.

**Can someone explain what the metaspace options MaxMetaspaceSize,MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio ,MinMetaspaceFreeRatio are?**

**How do I decide what the right size is?
what is the correct combination of these values to avoid outofmemory instance in production and reduce memory consumption ?**

Comment: I don’t understand, why developers keep messing around with these options. The default is *unlimited* metaspace. So if you don’t know which limitations are the best, don’t specify any limitations.

Comment: If we don't specify the limit , it can end up with huge native memory allocation.

Comment: Yeah, and if you specify a limit, it can end up with an `OutOfMemoryError`. The choice is yours…

Comment: If i don't set any metaspace attribute, Metaspace keeps on increasing even GC is not cleaning/unloading classes from metaspace. why this is happening ? what should i do to clean metaspace when GC is run?

Comment: You don’t. If a software has a memory leak, no JVM option will fix that. You have to fix the software.

Comment: If the same software has memory leak than why it is working fine with Java 6?  The code is scanned and it has no leak

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved.
Found that there are known issue with JAXB.

Used stringbuffer instead of string

Removed unnecessary instance of JAXBContext.

Refer this link

[Are there any memory utlization issue with JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745236/are-there-any-memory-utlization-issue-with-jaxb)